# I can't open a personalized extension with OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net

i'm developing a program that works with personalized extension, in example, there is a file with the .hi extension and i need to open it in an OpenFileDialog

i tried this

```vb
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
TextBox2.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.Title)
```

but it don't works, can someone help me please?

Comment: You should be doing: `My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.Filename)` instead

Comment: Why do you think the Title is a FileName?  You should also check if the user canceled the dialog, in which case, don't open the file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Filter property:

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "hi files (*.hi)|*.hi|All files (*.*)|*.*"
OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
```

You can find a better description in [.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: The custom extension part of the question is a red herring. Dig deeper: the `Title` property is *not* going to give the selected file name.  [JayV's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588054/i-cant-open-a-personalized-extension-with-openfiledialog#comment99754333_56588054) is correct.